# Special field record number in crysal report not show when record does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report asp.net visual studio 2012. I am showing table format data in crystal report and I am using special field record number as serial number but problem is when data not exist special field record number show 1.I want record number not display when data is not available.Which formula i will write to get rid of this problem.

I am getting following result when data is not available

```
SR                NAME
1
```

I do not want record number

Answer (score 0):

on your section expert under suppress condition you can write something like isnull(Name) or Name = "". Once that condition is true, it will suppress the entire row.